# Openscript generated xpath not matching

Tags: oracle-ats, oracle-openscript

Using the Xpath generator that comes built into OpenScript's editor, I have generated an xpath to select an attribute of a node:

```
/*[local-name()='test_results']/@tests
```

However, when pasted into http.solveXPath, I get errors saying that the variable could not be solved. I have confirmed that the result of the previous get is what I think it is, and I used the auto-saved content.txt as input to the generator, but it still isn't working. What else could be wrong?

(The beginning of my XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><test_results hostname="10.0.0.176" tests="2" failures="0" errors="0" timestamp="{ts '2014-01-10 11:15:47'}" time="125"><test_case number="1">
```

)

ETA: I'm really concerned with why the xpath generator isn't working, but for the sake of argument, I have also tried the following xpath statements to no effect:

```
/*test_results/@tests
/test_results/@tests
/test_results[@hostname='10.0.0.176']@tests
/test_results[@hostname='10.0.0.176']/@tests
/test_results[@hostname="10.0.0.176"]@tests
/test_results[@hostname="10.0.0.176"]/@tests
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed a support ticket with Oracle, and they confirmed that there appears to be a bug in the XPath generator. We have had a patch from them recently that may have caused this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope it helps.

The xpath has to start and end within the same entity and `local-name` doesn't appear to be valid on this line of your xml file.

```
/test_results[@hostname="10.0.0.176"]@tests
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the local-name is about, but the generator put it in; "/test_results/@tests" also didn't work

Comment: Try taking away the double quote marks and replace the hyphen for an underscore.

Comment: I was using quotes to set off the xpath from the text around it, they weren't in it. The hyphen was a typo

Comment: Have you tried `/test_results[@hostname="10.0.0.176"]@tests` to see if that solves the issue for you?

Comment: Just did. No change.